# How to keep monitoring a file to be created in a directory in TCL?

Tags: directory, timeout, tcl, monitoring, proc

How to keep on waiting till a file is created in a directory within 50 seconds in TCL and prints an error if the file is not created.
For eg, in /tmp directory I need to print a msg "File available" if a file named abc.txt is available within 50 seconds, and if not, print an error message "Timed-out!"

I tried the below code:

```
set lCount 0
while { [file exists $lFileCreated] == 0 } {
    if { $lCount > 50 } {
        puts "Timed-out!"
    }       
    after 5000
    incr lCount 5   
    puts "Waited for $lCount seconds for $lFileCreated"     
}
puts "File Available"
```

Is this the right way? I think it will fail for remote files.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/after.htm and https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M15 , but don't expect us to write the code for you.

Comment: The code you posted now looks pretty good.  You didn't mention remote files before - do you mean files mounted from a remote file server, or something else?

Comment: Yes, the files mounted from a remote server, it can be the case that the file I am waiting to be created is in a directory on a remote machine

Comment: We've never implemented access to OS filesystem monitoring (there have been feature requests but no effort). However, for remote filesystems polling is usually best anyway (networking adds weirdness of its it's own). Use `file stat`.

Comment: There's a tcl-inotify package available for Linux, but it doesn't seem to tie into the event system or otherwise support timeouts...